# What does "deleted" mean here?

Tags: plot-explanation, bicentennial-man

In *Bicentennial Man*, Andrew (Robot) search for alike robots. So he goes out & started scanning all other robots to find one alike him but the word "**Deleted**" appears on screen at end of each scanning operation he does.

[image]

What does "deleted" means here?

Comment: That whatever he wants to delete is deleted. :P

Comment: what exactly getting deleted then?

Comment: it's been a long time since I saw this movie, so I don't recall the scene in question specifically, but are we sure he isn't finding that all records of robots "like him" have been deleted (by someone else)?  Suggesting that robots who begin to exhibit self-awareness are deemed "defective" and taken out of service?

Comment: @Steve-O no, he went searching for other robots of the same model to see if they developed self-awareness, but found none that was working (I think they were all broken in some way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He isn't deleting records.  He was searching for robots similar to him, and the result for each one is 'Deleted,' which means that the robot he was searching for has been decommissioned and no longer exists, thus has been 'deleted.'

Answer (score 3):

I saw the movie a long time ago.

Andrew had this list with the robots he was going to look for. Either he deleted the record for the each robot he met that wasn't self-aware, or he marked the robot as "deleted" on his list. Doesn't seem to be specified which one is it in the movie.

Comment: Works as marked "deleted" or removed from his list, and could possibly be its way also to say "dead" for a robot.

Comment: @Larme I thought about the "dead" idea too